# Reading an Ogg Opus header to check the crc

Tags: python, file, crc32, ogg, opus

I decided to experiment with file formats and I'm using python to read said files.
Everything I have extracted from the Ogg header is correct, except the crc check. 
The [documentation](https://xiph.org/ogg/doc/framing.html) says you must check the entire header and page with the original crc check value set to 0. 
I'm wondering what steps I'm missing to get the expected result.

```py
import zlib
import struct

with open("sample3.opus", "rb") as f_:
    file_data = f_.read()


cp, ssv, htf, agp, ssn, psn, pc, ps = struct.unpack_from("<4sBBQIIIB", file_data, 0)
offset = struct.calcsize("<4sBBQIIIB")
segments = struct.unpack_from(f"<{ps}B", file_data, offset)

packet_size = 0

for num in segments:
    packet_size += num

header_size = offset + len(segments) + packet_size


# Copying the entire packet then changing the crc to 0.
header_copy = bytearray()
header_copy.extend(file_data[0:header_size])
struct.pack_into("<I", header_copy, struct.calcsize("<4sBBQII"), 0)

print(pc)
print(zlib.crc32(header_copy))
```

This script results in:

```
277013243
752049619
```

**The audio file I'm using:**

https://filesamples.com/formats/opus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zlib.crc32()` is not the CRC that they specify. They say the initial value and final exclusive-or is zero, whereas for `zlib.crc32()`, those values are both `0xffffffff`. They fail to specify whether their CRC is reflected or not, so you'd need to try both to see which it is.

*Update:*

I checked, and it's a forward CRC. Unfortunately, you can't use `zlib.crc32()` to calculate it. You can compute it with this:

```
def crc32ogg(seq):
    crc = 0
    for b in seq:
        crc ^= b << 24
        for _ in range(8):
            crc = (crc << 1) ^ 0x104c11db7 if crc & 0x80000000 else crc << 1
    return crc
```

Comment: It is a shame that they have this gap in the specification, I am glad someone clarified it

Comment: The specification linked in the question fully describes the CRC: "32 bit CRC value (direct algorithm, initial val and final XOR = 0, generator polynomial=0x04c11db7)."